# I AM TRYING TO GROUP USING MULTIPLE TABLE INNER JOIN OPERATOR IN SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, group-by, null

I am trying to get result **group by** "CreditVoucherId" if terminals null then merge, but not getting. i think there is some bug please help out this.
**This is my Codding..**

```
DECLARE @Fromdate date = '2021-07-26'; DECLARE @Todate date = '2021-07-26';
DECLARE @till01 VARCHAR(200) = 'ST-LO-01'; DECLARE @till02  VARCHAR(200) = 'ST-LO-02'; DECLARE @till03  VARCHAR(200) = 'ST-LO-03';
DECLARE @till04 VARCHAR(200) = 'ST-LO-04'; DECLARE @till05  VARCHAR(200) = 'ST-LO-05'; DECLARE @till06  VARCHAR(200) = 'ST-LO-06';
DECLARE @StringEmpty VARCHAR(200) = ''
   SELECT 
    CASE WHEN PtDt.TERMINAL NOT IN (@till01, @till02, @till03, @till04)  THEN PtDt.TERMINAL END AS "ReturnBy",
    PtDt.CREDITVOUCHERID
    ,CASE WHEN PtDt.TERMINAL IN (@till01, @till02, @till03, @till04)  THEN  PtDt.TERMINAL END AS "AgainstBy"
            FROM RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE SRT
    LEFT JOIN RETAILTRANSACTIONINFOCODETRANS Cinf ON Cinf.TRANSACTIONID = SRT.TRANSACTIONID
    LEFT JOIN RetailTransactionPaymentTrans PtDt on PtDt.TERMINAL = SRT.TERMINAL
WHERE PtDt.TRANSDATE >= @Fromdate AND PtDt.TRANSDATE <= @todate AND SRT.TYPE = 2
    AND PtDt.CREDITVOUCHERID <> @StringEmpty AND isnull(PtDt.CREDITVOUCHERID,@StringEmpty) <> @StringEmpty
Group by PtDt.CREDITVOUCHERID ,PtDt.TERMINAL
Order by  PtDt.CREDITVOUCHERID desc
```

**My Result Is**

| Date | ReturnBy | CreditVoucherId | AgainstBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-26 | ST-LO-05 | BP-099254 | NULL |
| 2021-07-26 | NULL | BP-099254 | ST-LO-01 |

**And my Expected output** (mearge both lines by 3rd Column "CreditVoucherId")

| Date | ReturnBy | CreditVoucherId | AgainstBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-26 | ST-LO-05 | BP-099254 | ST-LO-01 |

Comment: You can't be using Postgres if that query actually runs.

Comment: For the same CreditVoucherId, could multiple records have ReturnBy/AgainstBy populated? If they could be, then what result would you expect?

Comment: @NickW the **ReturnBy** and the **AgainstBy** are the same column.
Which is obtained through (case operator). and my Expected output (mearge both lines group by 3rd Column "CreditVoucherId")

Comment: Hmmm... the ReturnBy and the AgainstBy  are not the same column - they are 2 different calculated columns. My question still stands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use STRING_AGG with an empty string a separator over ReturnBY and AgainsBY columns to vertically coalesce the NULL values with the non NULL ones.